# Repeating UIAlert code over and over

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this code:

```
-(IBAction)action2:(id)sender{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:@"If you press of a new group with the name you have set will be created" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Ok", nil];
[alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([title isEqualToString:@"Ok"])
{

    NSString *destDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/sandbox/%@/", namegroup.text];

    NSString *filename5 = namegroup.text;
    NSString *filename6 = @"group";
    NSString *filename7 = @"groupdata";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath5 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename7]];

    NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];
    [titles addObject:filename5];

    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];
    [keys addObject:filename6];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:titles forKeys:keys];

    NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONRepresentation];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [jsonData writeToFile: getImagePath5 atomically: YES];

    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename7 toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:getImagePath5];

}

}
```

If I press Ok button, the code is repeated over and over. how can I repeat it only 1 time??

Comment: Is the action that is calling action2: within a Loop?

Comment: no, it is just the press of a button

Comment: Are you sure you're not invoking it anywhere else in the code? Are you displaying an alert view anywhere else in the same class?

Comment: no, I am sure, only from the button

Comment: Which action of the button? `Touch up inside` or something else?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing in action2: that calls itself to repeat. It must be outside of the action2: method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was another alert with the same cancel title, and when this was pressed it re-launched the same code. Thanks however for the help.